# sed + replace word on directory PATH

Tags: regex, sed

How to replace the

```
<x>
```

with word Before_last_dir only on the dir that located before the last dir (according to this example – dir4)

```
 echo "/dir1/dir2/dir3<x>/dir4<x>/dir5<x>" |sed s"/<x>/Before_last_dir/g"
```

Another example

```
echo "/dirA<x>/dirB<x>/dirC<x> >" |sed s"/<x>/Before_last_dir/g"
```

should be

```
/dirA<x>/dirBBefore_last_dir/dirC<x>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "/dir1/dir2/dir3<x>/dir4<x>/dir5<x>" | sed -E "s/<x>(\/[^\/]+)$/Before_last_dir\1/g"
/dir1/dir2/dir3<x>/dir4Before_last_dir/dir5<x>
```

(-E means sed is using POSIX extended regular expressions)

Alternatively, without -E (as -E may not be available on some systems):

```
$ echo "/dir1/dir2/dir3<x>/dir4<x>/dir5<x>" | sed "s/<x>\(\/[^\/]\{1,\}\)$/Before_last_dir\1/"
/dir1/dir2/dir3<x>/dir4Before_last_dir/dir5<x>
```

This should work everywhere. (EDIT: changed the "+" operator to the POSIX "{1,}" since "+" is a GNU extension, not in POSIX.

Comment: @Tom: That's weird, it works for me (Linux Fedora 13) just as displayed here. It may be an issue with sed - are you using another version than GNU sed?

Here: GNU sed version 4.2.1; GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu).

Comment: You can reduce some of that escaping by using alternative delimiters and `g` is unecessary: `sed -E 's|<x>(/[^/]+)$|Before_last_dir\1|'`. GNU `sed` understands `-E` for compatibility, but the documented option is `-r`.